# javascript filter gridview with chechboxlist in asp.net c#

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, performance

I'm looking a way to filter a GridView with its contents coming from a datasource by checking a MultiselectDropDown Checkboxlist in the header template. The GridView should refresh without a postback (Javascript or jquery or something from client side) and display only rows matched the checkbox.
I don't know how to do it. Could someone give me an example to show me how to achieve this goal?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Here is an article which explains how to make an asynchronous call to the server using plain `javascript` (https://www.sitepoint.com/guide-vanilla-ajax-without-jquery/) and here is one which explains how `ajax` works in `JQuery` (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Thanks for the link. but the examples given here is php. I don't know how to use it for gridview and checkboxlist. I just need an example for asp.net and gridview to learn more. Could someone help me please?

Comment: What type of ASP.Net app is it?  WebForms, MVC, etc.?

Comment: It is the WebForms

Comment: Are you using UpdatePanels?

Comment: yes. UpdatePanel and ScriptManager

Comment: If you could post what you have already (even if it's just the .aspx page with a gridview and the HTML for the dropdown/checkboxlist) then we could help you from there.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty simple, crude example of a GridView being updated asynchronously based on selections made in a CheckBoxList.  You should be able to modify my example to meet your needs, including loading actual data and replacing the checkboxlist with whatever control you would like.

I added the times at the top and the bottom so you can see that each asynchronous postback causes only a partial page load.

**Default.aspx:**

```
<p><%= "Initial page load: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") %></p>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upTest" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>

        <p>Limit Results By Department:</p>
        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblMyList" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Accounting" Value="Accounting"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Sales" Value="Sales"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Service" Value="Service"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:CheckBoxList>

        <asp:Button ID="btnDepartments" CssClass="btn btn-primary" runat="server" OnClick="btnDepartments_Click" Text="Filter" />

        <asp:GridView ID="gvMyGrid" CssClass="table table-striped" runat="server"></asp:GridView>

        <p><%= "Latest Async Postback:" + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") %></p>

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**Default.aspx.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace TestWebFormsApp_2018_08_24 {
    public partial class _Default : Page {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack) {
                // Do stuff on first page load
                GetData();
            }
        }

        protected void GetData(List<String> filter = null) {

            // Build a test table
            DataTable dtData = new DataTable("EmployeeData");
            dtData.Columns.Add(new DataColumn { ColumnName = "ID", DataType = typeof(int) });
            dtData.Columns.Add(new DataColumn { ColumnName = "Name", DataType = typeof(String) });
            dtData.Columns.Add(new DataColumn { ColumnName = "Department", DataType = typeof(String) });

            // Add some test data
            dtData.Rows.Add(new Object[] { 1, "Richard", "Sales" });
            dtData.Rows.Add(new Object[] { 2, "Dale", "Sales" });
            dtData.Rows.Add(new Object[] { 3, "Nancy", "Service" });
            dtData.Rows.Add(new Object[] { 4, "Robyn", "Sales" });
            dtData.Rows.Add(new Object[] { 5, "Henry", "Service" });
            dtData.Rows.Add(new Object[] { 6, "Conrad", "Accounting" });

            // Select the data based on the filter
            DataView dv = new DataView();
            dv.Table = dtData;

            if (filter != null && filter.Count > 0) {
                // Include items that match the filter
                String filterString = "";
                foreach (String dept in filter) {
                    filterString += "'" + dept + "',";
                }
                dv.RowFilter = "Department IN (" + filterString + ")";
            }

            // Bind the gridview to the filtered data
            //gvMyGrid.DataSource = dtData.Select("Department='Sales'");
            gvMyGrid.DataSource = dv;
            gvMyGrid.DataBind();

        }

        protected void btnDepartments_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            List<String> filter = new List<String>();
            foreach (ListItem item in cblMyList.Items) {
                if (item.Selected) {
                    filter.Add(item.Value);
                }
            };
            GetData(filter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but I need to filter the gridview from client side with javascript or jquery not from sever side. please help me. I don't know how to filter DropDownCheckBoxes with javascript.

Comment: Do you still need help? If so, is DropDownCheckBox a control you are already using? Can you include an example of one?

Comment: I still need help. could you take your code and show me with it how to filter a gridview with checkboxlist in javascript or jquery? I'am new in asp programming.

Comment: If you're using Update Panels and ScriptManager, the example above would be the "normal" way to do this, as the framework handles all of the scripting required to only update what is inside the UpdatePanel. Also, you're getting a fresh copy of the data each time, including any changes. You can filter exclusively on the client side, but you're defeating the point of using UpdatePanels & ScriptManager, and changes to the data won't be included. But if that's still what you want, I can update my example to show you how to do that.

Comment: that's what I want filter Gridview exclusively on the client side. Thanks

Comment: can you update your example to show you how to filter Gridview exclusively on the client side. Thanks